# ob der Tatsache

Tags: translation

I have come across this strange use of "ob" where "ob der Tatsache dass" appears to mean "because of the fact that".

[Source](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/smalltalk/herzblatt-geschichten/herzblatt-geschichten-der-kuckuck-macht-mir-gaensehaut-16646887.html).

> Jens Spahn schließlich wurde von Bunte mal einschmeichelnd „der
>   prominente CDU-Gesundheitsminister“ genannt, was ob der Tatsache, dass
>   Spahn tatsächlich prominenter ist als andere im Kabinett (oder, Frau
>   Karliczek?) okay ist.

None of the standard dictionaries mention this use. I have checked Collins, Oxford and even Duden.

Comment: Compare Greek *apo* "off" https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/how-did-apo-shift-from-signifying-off-away-to-because-of not exactly the same, off course. There was something about *again, against* that meant roughly "towards", if not "for", that I can't quite remember. \*jabai (whence conj. *ob*, En *if*) reminds a bit of *bei*, too, by the way.

Comment: What's the question? Your text only suggests it.

Comment: Is there a way of voting down stupid comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably search for "ob" in its role as conjunction, but here it's a preposition. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ob_Praeposition shows some example uses of "ob" + genitive. As Duden says, today it's no longer common to use it that way.

Comment: [dict.cc mentions this as well](http://dict.cc?s=ob)

Comment: *Und ob es das ist!* naja, beinahe.

Comment: To say that  *ob* is a conjunction and *ob+genitive* is the use, is not to answer the question. The meaning remains unknown. Please do not write only-link answers, could you extract the information of the source?

Comment: @c.p. I don't see a question.

Comment: @c.p. The question that I answered is: Why didn't I find something, e.g. in Duden. And gave a link to where I found something in Duden. OP answered the question about the meaning of the phrase himself already.

Comment: Wo behauptest du das in der Antwort? Das steht ja nirgends.

Answer (score 1):

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ob#Etymology_2_2):

> 1. (formal, literary, + dative or genitive) on account of

To give you synonymous expressions: angesichts; in Anbetracht